# Question about ring isomorphism out of a quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $f:R\rightarrow S$ is a map of commutative rings with $1$. Further suppose that $I$ is an ideal of $R$ contained in the kernel of $f$. This induces a map on the quotient $f':R/I\rightarrow S$. Suppose further that $f'$ is an isomorphism.

Is it true then that $I=\ker f$? Certainly $I\subset \ker f $ by I am not sure how to see the opposite inclusion.

Comment: if $x\in \text{ker} f$ then $f(x)=0$ so $f'(x+I)=f'(I)$ so $x+I=I$ so $x\in I$

Comment: So then is this true regardless of the isomorphism assumption?

Comment: isomorphism means $f'$ is bijective, so $f'(x+I)=f'(I)$ implies $x+I=I$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, we can say more: given a ring morphism $f : R\to S$ and an ideal $I\subseteq\ker f,$ we have $\ker f = I$ if and only if $f' : R/I\to S$ is injective.

Suppose we have $f : R\to S$ and an ideal $I\subseteq\ker f$ such that the induced map $f' : R/I\to S$ is injective. Then if $x\in\ker f,$ it follows that $f'(x + I) = 0.$ Injectivity of $f'$ implies that $x+I = I,$ so that $x\in I.$ Thus, $\ker f  = I.$

Conversely, if $I = \ker f,$ then the first isomorphism theorem tells us that $f' : R/\ker f\to S$ is an isomorphism onto the image of $S,$ and is in particular injective.